# Web Worker Offscreen Canvas toBlob latency

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, offscreen-canvas

I have a hidden canvas in a react app that I send to a web worker using `transferControlToOffscreen` ([code](https://github.com/micahg/ntt/blob/release/0.0.37/src/utils/worker.ts#L19)).

Everything is working, but after updating the canvas (`fillRect` for example) the worker signals the main thread using `postMessage` ([code](https://github.com/micahg/ntt/blob/release/0.0.37/public/worker.js#L104)).

The main thread then converts the canvas `toBlob` and uploads it ([code](https://github.com/micahg/ntt/blob/release/0.0.37/src/components/ContentEditor/ContentEditor.tsx#L298)).

If I put the worker's `postMessage` inside a `setTimeout` callback for about 500ms everything works as expected. If I call `postMessage` immediately, the blob actually contains the canvas data before the update was made.

I don't really have any experience to base it on, but I'd have expected that the blob would immediately reflect the up-to-date canvas data. It *feels* like latency but react is also in the mix -- I just wouldn't have expected the render loop to affect a hidden the canvas contents.

Is the delay expected or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the delay is expected.
The *placeholder canvas* (the one that stays in the main thread) is updated with the `OffscreenCanvas` buffer only when the event-loop enters the ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps (basically when the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) callbacks are executed).

So you'd have to wait for the next such rendering update in your worker before sending your message to the main thread. (Note that there used to be a `commit()` method, that's still specced, but which is going to be removed any time now).

But the best might actually be to [convert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas/convertToBlob) your `OffscreenCanvas` from the Worker thread and send the Blob directly to the main thread.

```js
// In your worker
const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob();
postMessage(blob);
```

Comment: This is excellent -- a much better solution -- I was under the impression that the blob couldn't be transferred at all (I was trying to include it previously in transfer list and getting an error).

Thanks @kaiido

Comment: You're welcome. And indeed, there is no need to *transfer* a Blob. The data isn't copied around, `Blob` objects just hold a pointer to the actual data, and some metadata to check the pointer points to the same data as when the Blob was created. So it can be copied around without an issue. The actual data could even be on a remote location (e.g. iCloud), or even long deleted, the `Blob` object wouldn't know. It's only when using one of the reading APIs that the data is actually accessed.